# MariaDB update error inner join and select

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, mariadb, iban

I hope you can help me again, thanks already for pointing me to the right direction with creating the check digit for the new IBAN in Germany. I am now trying to update our membership database with the newly calculated BIC and IBAN but seem to have a problem with the UPDATE statement on the MariaDB MySQL database, despite the fact that I think I got the syntax right.

All I am trying to do is set the two fields "konto_bic" and "konto_iban" in the table "mitglieder" from the SELECT statement which creates a temporary table called b with the columns "id", "bic" and "iban". The "id" is the same in the two tables.

Here is my first try:

```
update a
set a.`konto_bic` = b.`BIC`, a.`konto_iban` = b.`IBAN`
from `mitglieder` a
INNER JOIN (SELECT m.`id`, m.`nachname`, m.`vorname`, m.`konto_bank`, m.`konto_blz`, m.`konto_nummer`, k.`bic` AS 'BIC', CONCAT('DE',LPAD(98-MOD(CONVERT(CONCAT(m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0'),'1314','00'), decimal(24)),97),2,'0'),m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0')) AS 'IBAN'
FROM `mitglieder` m
LEFT JOIN `konvert_bic_blz` k
ON m.`konto_blz` = k.`blz`
ORDER BY m.`nachname`, m.`vorname`) b
ON a.`id` = b.`id`
```

However, this produced an error and I tried this instead:

```
update `mitglieder` a
set a.`konto_bic` = b.`bic`, a.`konto_iban` = b.`iban`
FROM (SELECT m.`id` as 'id', k.`bic` as 'bic', CONCAT('DE',LPAD(98-MOD(CONVERT(CONCAT(m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0'),'1314','00'), decimal(24)),97),2,'0'),m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0')) AS 'iban'
FROM `mitglieder` m
LEFT JOIN `konvert_bic_blz` k
ON m.`konto_blz` = k.`blz`) b
WHERE a.`id` = b.`id`
```

That also did not get me any further (error from DB).

Can anyone see what my syntax error might be?
Thank you in advance for your help

Stephan

Comment: could you show us the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below SQL

```
UPDATE `mitglieder` a,
       (SELECT m.`id` AS 'id',
               k.`bic` AS 'bic',
               CONCAT('DE',LPAD(98-MOD(CONVERT(CONCAT(m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0'),'1314','00'), decimal(24)),97),2,'0'),m.`konto_blz`,LPAD(m.`konto_nummer`,10,'0')) AS 'iban'
        FROM `mitglieder` m
        LEFT JOIN `konvert_bic_blz` k ON m.`konto_blz` = k.`blz`) b
SET a.`konto_bic` = b.`bic`, a.`konto_iban` = b.`iban`
WHERE a.`id` = b.`id`
```

UPDATE Syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on MariaDB 10.2.6 :

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'

UPDATE "test"."user" AS "a"
INNER JOIN "test"."user_profile" AS "c" ON "c".user_id = "a".id
INNER JOIN "test"."profile" AS "d" ON "d".id = "c".profile_id
SET "a".firstname = 'laurent'
WHERE "a".id = 3;
```

And it works :)